# Why the "return 0" statement did not reach?

Tags: c, loops, return, fork

Here is my program:

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        int id = fork();
        if(id != 0) {
            printf("This process is running under parent process \n");
        }
        else {
            printf("This process id = %d, is a child process of parent process id = %d\n", getpid(),getppid());
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When it finished the first loop,I assume that it should print    "This process is running under parent process \n" then hit the `return 0;` statement. But It seems it didn't work as my expectation.

Here is my output

```
This process is running under parent process 
This process id = 839, is a child process of parent process id = 1
```

I need an explain about this.

Comment: So what is the behavior you actually observe?

Comment: "First loop" - there won't be any other loop anyway.

Comment: I think what you want is for the `return 0` to be inside the `else` (unless you want child processes to spawn childs of their own) and then outside the `for` for the parent to wait all the child processes to finish before doing `return 0`

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the parent process exited before the child process called `getppid()`, so the child process was reparented to init.

Since you didn't get any more output, clearly `return 0;` was reached.

`fork()` is called once, but returns twice. That's how you get new processes. The loop is unnecessary.

In addition, `fork()` returns a variable of type `pid_t` not `int`. Seems safe to assign to type `int`, but I have been burnt once.